addPageRequestListener never stops, it fetches data indefinitely
addPageRequestListener is called indefinitely. It fetches the data for next pages without having to scroll.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what.
class PostPage extends StatefulWidget { const PostPage({super.key});

  @override
  PostState createState() => PostState();
}

class PostState extends State<PostPage> {
  final FirebaseFirestore fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final String currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  static const _pageSize = 10;
  final PagingController<DocumentSnapshot?, DocumentSnapshot>
      _pagingController = PagingController(firstPageKey: null);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
      _fetchPage(pageKey);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _fetchPage(DocumentSnapshot? lastDocument) async {
    try {
      final query = fireStore
          .collection("Posts")
          .orderBy("dateTime", descending: true)
          .limit(_pageSize);

      final snapshot = lastDocument == null
          ? await query.get()
          : await query.startAfterDocument(lastDocument).get();

      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

      final isLastPage = snapshot.docs.length < _pageSize;
      if (isLastPage) {
        _pagingController.appendLastPage(snapshot.docs);
      } else {
        final nextPageKey = snapshot.docs.last;
        _pagingController.appendPage(snapshot.docs, nextPageKey);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      _pagingController.error = error;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          '자유게시판',
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .bodyLarge!
              .copyWith(color: Colors.black87),
        ),
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.backgroundColor,
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0.0),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.grey.shade200,
            height: 1.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () => Future.sync(() {
          _pagingController.refresh();
          loadBlockedUsers();
        }),
        child: PagedListView<DocumentSnapshot?, DocumentSnapshot>(
          pagingController: _pagingController,
          builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<DocumentSnapshot>(
            itemBuilder: (context, item, index) {
              if (_blockedUsers.contains(item['uid'])) {
                return const SizedBox.shrink(); // 차단된 사용자의 게시물은 표시하지 않습니다.
              }
              return (item['image'] != null
                  ? item['avatarUrl'] == null
                      ? (FeedPageBody(
                          uid: item['uid'],
                          name: item['name'],
                          content: item['contents'],
                          photoUrls: item['image'],
                          dateTime: item['dateTime'],
                          documentId: item.id,
                          currentUserId: currentUserId,
                          anoym: item['anoym'],
                          commentsCount: item['commentsCount'],
                        ))
                      : (FeedPageBody(
                          uid: item['uid'],
                          name: item['name'],
                          content: item['contents'],
                          photoUrls: item['image'],
                          dateTime: item['dateTime'],
                          documentId: item.id,
                          currentUserId: currentUserId,
                          anoym: item['anoym'],
                          commentsCount: item['commentsCount'],
                          avatarUrl: item['avatarUrl'],
                        ))
                  : item['avatarUrl'] == null
                      ? (FeedPageBody(
                          uid: item['uid'],
                          name: item['name'],
                          content: item['contents'],
                          dateTime: item['dateTime'],
                          documentId: item.id,
                          currentUserId: currentUserId,
                          anoym: item['anoym'],
                          commentsCount: item['commentsCount'],
                        ))
                      : (FeedPageBody(
                          uid: item['uid'],
                          name: item['name'],
                          content: item['contents'],
                          dateTime: item['dateTime'],
                          documentId: item.id,
                          currentUserId: currentUserId,
                          anoym: item['anoym'],
                          commentsCount: item['commentsCount'],
                          avatarUrl: item['avatarUrl'],
                        )));
            },
            noItemsFoundIndicatorBuilder: (context) => const Center(
              child: Text("표시할 게시물이 없어요", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: floatingButtons(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pagingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
  

Do you know what is happening?
I've tried to add CustomScrollView and PagedSliverList but it did not work.
